# How can I set values for variables that are declared on one line?

Tags: vb.net, variables

I have a list of variables that are being created on one line.

`Dim strFirstname, strMiddleName, strLastName As String`

Is it possible to set the values for all of them at once? I know this doesn't work, but this is what I'm trying to do :

`Dim strFirstname, strMiddleName, strLastName As String = ""`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I liked the examples, but I just needed to set the values so that the compiler would leave me alone. I have another function that sets all the values that I'm passing these strings into. I wanted to set them to pretty much nothing, just so it would leave me alone. I ended up using this:

```
Dim strFirstname, strMiddleName, strLastName As New String(String.Empty)
```

Comment: then you don't need to initialize it

Comment: @Daniel do you mean because I'm setting the values in a function later on?

Comment: yea. its just empty operations.

Answer (score 2):

If you want different values, this should work:

```
Dim strFirstname As String = "First name", strMiddleName  As String = "middle name", strLastName As String = "last name"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you truely want one line instantiating them all, create an object to hold this data instead, e.g.

```
...
person.Firstname
person.MiddleName
person.LastName
...
```

Then populate them in the constructor, e.g.

```
Dim person As New Person("first","middle","last")
```

Seems like a cleaner option if your objects are all related to a specific idea/entity.